# Use for and If loops in R to convert data

Tags: r

I am trying to convert my matrix to another format in R but since I don't have much coding experience with for/if loops I fail. Any help is appreciated.

A demonstration of my matrix is as follows:

```
S   K1  K1  K2  K2  K3  K3  K4  K4  K5  K5   
1   A   P   A   A   A   A   P   A   A   A   
2   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   P   P   
3   A   P   A   A   A   A   P   A   A   A   
4   A   P   A   A   A   A   P   A   A   A   
5   A   P   A   A   A   A   A   A   P   A
```

A=ABSENT P=PRESENT

I would like to retrieve the column names for present columns and print them. Each sample has 2 P columns. So the end result should be

```
S   V1  V1  
1   K1  K4      
2   K5  K5      
3   K1  K4      
4   K1  K4  
5   K1  K5
```

I know it is a simple for/if loop but I cannot come up with a solutuion. You have any codes to fix this?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Is your data really in a matrix or a data.frame?

Comment: you have column with the same name? And why did you decide you need a loop here? I would go with `indx <- which(df == "P", arr.ind = TRUE) ; matrix(colnames(df)[indx[order(indx[, "row"]), "col"]], ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)` (if `df` is your dataframe/matrix)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have columns with the same name. I decided to go with the loop because I am not familiar with r and I am thinking as a shell scripting. So can I use this with same colnames or should I change them?

Comment: Did you try my code?

Comment: I tried. Actually it is what I wanted but I cannot print the result as a .txt or .csv since it is an index. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(df,1))[value=="P"][order(S),as.list(sub("[.].*","",variable)),by=S]
   S V1 V2
1: 1 K1 K4
2: 2 K5 K5
3: 3 K1 K4
4: 4 K1 K4
5: 5 K1 K5
```

Comment: Very nice solution. If speed or memory is of concern, using `setDT` before `melt` will help

Comment: It seems nice but I got an error "Error in eval(.massagei(isub), x, parent.frame()) : 
  object 'value' not found"

Comment: what are the column names when you run `setDT(melt(df,1))`?

Comment: 0101, 0101, 0102, 0102, 0201, 0201 ... 596 columns with different names

Comment: my question is when you run `a=setDT(melt(df,1));names(a)` what do you get??

Comment: "sample.id" "0101"      "0101"      "0102"      "0102"      "0103"      "0103"      "0201"      "0201"      "0202"  basically my column names

Comment: the moment you melt your data you should have it in long format thus will have three columns..

Comment: I got this: "sample.id" "variable"  "value"

Comment: so when i did 
a=setDT(melt(hla_a,1))[value=="P"][order(sample.id),as.list(sub("[.].*","",variable)),by=sample.id]
i got an error: 'Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(melt(hla_a, 1))[value == "P"], order(sample.id),  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group'

Comment: Nice so as you can tell there is a column called `value` now you can try `a[value=="P"][order(sample.id),as.list(sub("[.].*","",variable)),by=sample.id]`

Comment: same error: Error in `[.data.table`(a[value == "P"], order(sample.id), as.list(sub("[.].*",  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group

Comment: mhh.. That means there are other rows with more "P" than  the others

Comment: you can do something like `b=a[value=="P"][order(sample.id),.(V1=sub("[.].*","",variable),V2=sequence(.N)),by=sample.id];dcast(b,S~V2,value.var = "V1",fill=NA)`

Answer (score 0):

One of the many available options can be as:

```
df_res <- cbind(df[1],t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x)names(df)[which(x=="P")+1])))

#write result to a csv file
write.csv(df_res, file = "d:\\MyData.csv",row.names=FALSE)

#   S  1  2
# 1 1 K1 K4
# 2 2 K5 K5
# 3 3 K1 K4
# 4 4 K1 K4
# 5 5 K1 K5
```

I'm just wondering how OP has created such matrix/data.frame.

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"S   K1  K1  K2  K2  K3  K3  K4  K4  K5  K5   
1   A   P   A   A   A   A   P   A   A   A   
2   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   P   P   
3   A   P   A   A   A   A   P   A   A   A   
4   A   P   A   A   A   A   P   A   A   A   
5   A   P   A   A   A   A   A   A   P   A",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Change the name of columns 
names(df) <- sub("(.*)\\.\\d+","\\1",names(df))
```

Comment: By the way I noticed now that R did not permit to have colums with the same name and my colum names are K1, K1.1, K2, K2.2...
I am that noob!

Comment: @Mystra But you can change the column names using `names(df)`. If you notice I have changed it in `data` using `names(df) <- c('S','K1', 'K1',  'K2',  'K2',  'K3',  'K3',  'K4',  'K4',  'K5',  'K5')` You can try it at your end.

Comment: @Mystra No worries. learning is a process that takes time. Everyone was a noob at some point time.

Comment: It's pretty ugly, but this will append `.1` to the names of every odd numbered column in your data frame:  `names(df[seq.int(ncol(df))%%2 == 0]) <- paste0(names(df[seq.int(ncol(df))%%2 == 0]), '.1')`

Comment: @Mystra What's your column names at present? I'm sure we can sort it out easily. Just let me know 10-20 column names.

Comment: I tried colnames(df)<-gsub(".1","",colnames(df)) , but it didn't worked..

Comment: @Mystra I have modified my answer to include a way to change the name of the column. Basically its `names(df) <- sub("(.*)\\.\\d+","\\1",names(df))`

Comment: Your code worked pretty good for me the only issue is that I cannot use write.txt to get the data. Is there any way around for this?

Comment: csv is ok i think

Comment: @Mystra I have updated my answer to include code to write to a file. The name of the file have chosen as `d:\\MyData.csv`. You can choose per your choice.